# Where are the Nexuiz servers?

Tags: nexuiz

Several months ago, my PC Nexuiz installation stopped showing the normal list of internet servers for multi-player gaming.  I know that many folks have moved to Xonotic, but are the Nexuiz servers really all gone?

I am running the old open-source v2.5 version by Lord Havoc, before the split with the commercialized one in steam.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [main site](http://www.nexuiz.com), the servers are very much alive. The game runs through steam and xbox live, suggesting that you would at least are empty servers, if this was an issue of nobody playing.

That said, there is a new version of the game, operating through Steam. Unless you are operating the Steam version, your game won't be up-to-date enough to see current servers.

As far as the original version goes, it appears to be abandoned. While there is a site, both Google and Avast report it to be unsafe, and potentially hacked.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am running the old open-source 2.5 version by Lord Havoc, before the split with the commercialized one in steam....

Comment: Then Timelord's issue seems to be the answer, since the old version is no longer maintained.